# React Native Linking: read the url parameters from Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: android, react-native, parameters, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I don't receive the parameters from the url in the dynamic link.

I'm on a React Native Cli project on Andorid.
I've set on `AndoridManifest.xml` inside `<activity>`

```
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="mydynimiclink.page.link" android:pathPrefix="/app" android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="mydynimiclink.page.link" android:pathPrefix="/app" android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

In the React Native app I set

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => parseUrl(url));
Linking.addEventListener('url', url => parseUrl(url));

  const parseUrl = url => {
    if (url) {
      console.log(url);
    }
```

The dynamic link that Firebase creates for the verification email is this:

```
https://mydynimiclink.page.link/app?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=Yfhwu6N1pXEAbwfVJVNCkBjiW9Acd3miGjGI1C-FHG8AAAFwV9YjsQ&apiKey=HIzaSyAHb1DS429YSibHsweHPAGIbaOFfsRLPmc&lang=en
```

It opens the app and I receive correctly the url like this:

```
{"url": "https://mydynimiclink.page.link/app"}
```

But I don't receive the parameters after the ?
Without those I can't parse the url and use it properly.

**How can I get these parameters?**

Comment: which version of firebase u are using v5 or 6

Comment: I'm using the v6

Comment: android installation is done correctly? did u add new ReactNativeFirebaseDynamicLinksPackage() in main application in packagelist

Comment: add the full code from above were u are checking for the  licks

Comment: Thank you @Ashwith. I found the problem. I didn't whitelist the link in Firebase.

Comment: I've noticed that there is a problem on iOS. When I run the link Safari reloads in loop the same page. 
I've set the RCTLinkingManager in AppDelegate.m, but doesn't open the app and loads and reloads the url... any idea?